# How to share an image and a URL in Facebook from iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am writing an iOS app where a user creates an image after some edits which is stored in the server, I want the user to be able to share a modified thumbnail (which is a different image) and a associated URL to social apps/sites. I am facing issue with Facebook. I have used `UIActivityViewController`:

```
UIActivityViewController *avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[someNSString,someNSURLUserImage,thumbnailUIImage] applicationActivities:nil];
```

I have also tried direct FBShareSDK:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *shareContent = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
shareContent.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString: someNSURLUserImage];
shareContent.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:someNSURLofthumbnailImage];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:shareContent delegate:self];
```

Both the approaches have same effect, the some `NSURLUserImage` gets shared but the thumbnail image does't. Is there any approach anybody knows where I can share the URL as well as the thumbnail image, where the thumbnail image is separate from the image from URL.

My final objective is: when other uses click on that URL, I can do deeplinking and open up my app. something very similar to posting youtube video on Facebook where it shows as a thumbnail and some text, when you click it will open up and play.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to be working correctly; just make sure that `someNSURLofthumbnailImage` is a valid URL. If the share does not happen through the SafariViewController (iOS 9+ uses SafariViewController), make sure that you are using the latest version of the native Facebook app.